# How to Have Multiple Declarations of "li span" in my CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So I needed to create a bulleted list on my site, and I wanted to make the bullet points bigger, while keeping the text the same size. The code below served my purpose just fine, but I am wondering what I would do if I needed to use the below code and `li span` again somewhere else on my site and make my font size 40px, for example. I used the following code for my current single use:

```
ul {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: disc;
}
    
li {
  font-size: 20px;
}

li span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: use css classes

Comment: @Johannes so would it be like "li.classtest span" and then just also add the <span> tag to my text? Sorry, still learning.

Comment: Yes, or even `ul.myclass li span { ... }`, so in HTML you only have to add the class to the `ul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding classes as per the font-size or the required css rules like this:

```css
ul {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
list-style: disc;
}

li span {
  font-size: 20px;
}

li.list12px {
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.list40px {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my_ul_list">
  <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></li>
  <li class="list12px"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></li>
  <li class="list40px"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With this method will I be able to keep my enlarged bullet points too though?

Comment: Hi @kingklick , I have edited the code. Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: Yup! This looks about right! I just have to play around with the padding etc. to get it centered nicely I believe, but the bullets are larger with the text the same size. Thank you! Marked as answered and upvoted :)